# Is it possible to deduce type of non-type template parameter in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

C++17 has this nice feature which allows you to declare non-type template arguments with `auto` keyword:

```
template<auto a>
void foo();
```

which allows this parameters type to be deduced, like that:

```
foo<3>() <-- a has deduced type of 'int'
```

Unfortunately, I have to use a compiler which doesn't support C++17 and doesn't fully support C++11 either (it lacks support for standard library).
So my question is: is it possible to achieve the same effect using C++11?

The only way that I could come up with is using a macro:

```
template< typename T, T a>
void foo();

#define CALL_FOO( x ) foo< decltype(x), x >()
```

Comment: No, it's not possible, which is why it was added in C++17

Comment: Why not change your signature to `template <typename T> foo(T a)`? Then you can just call `foo(x)`.

Comment: The macro you show *is* the way to do this pre-C++17.

Comment: @KerrekSB it's a very simplified example, I actually need an instance of a template for very non-type parameter.

Comment: @Justin, okay, I just wanted to be sure. I thought maybe there is some black template magic to do it 'the olde way'.

Comment: Why do you need `a` at compile time?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I'm making analog of std::function without dynamic memory allocatoin, It's a trick to have a static object inside every template instance.

Comment: You can change your non-type parameter to a type one and use the specialization of the template for something like `std::integral_constant`.

Comment: @Constructor unfortunately, my non-type parameter is not an integral value, it's actually a member pointer. So the need to pass type and non-type  parameter will just "move" to another template.

Comment: Member pointers [can be handled via `std::integral_constant`, too](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1ffdc199c8f6e87).

Comment: @Constructor so.. what good will it do? Since it's `template<class T, T v>
struct integral_constant` I'd still have to type `decltype(x), x`, it just will be moved to the integral_constant. I want to get rid of the repitition.

Comment: Then you should use a macro as you wrote in your question.

Comment: @Constructor thanks. Can you make an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: What answer do you want me to write? Should it contain an example with `std::integral_constant`?

Comment: @Constructor Just summirize our conversation here? I guess there won't be any harm if it will contain an example.